# Message driven bean does not receive message from other nodes in the cluster

Tags: java, jboss, jms-topic, wildfly-23

I have a Wildfly 23 cluster with two nodes (node-1, node-2) running the standalone-full-ha profile.
The two cluster nodes boot and communicate with each other correctly (as far as I can judge).

My intention is to send a JMS message on a topic from node-1 and have message driven beans (MDB) on node-1 and node-2 consume this message.

The MDB code:

```
import javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty;
import javax.ejb.MessageDriven;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;

@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Topic"), 
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationLookup", 
            propertyValue = "java:/jms/topic/myTopic"), 
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "maxSession", propertyValue = "1")
})
public class ClusteredEventListener implements MessageListener {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(final Message message) {
        // consume message
    }

}
```

The message publisher code:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.ObjectMessage;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.Topic;
import javax.jms.TopicConnection;
import javax.jms.TopicConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.TopicSession;

@Startup
@ApplicationScoped
public class ClusteredEventSender {

    @Resource(lookup = "java:/jms/topic/myTopic")
    private Topic topic;

    @Resource(mappedName = "java:/ConnectionFactory")
    private TopicConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    public void broadcast(final Serializable event) {
        try {
            try (TopicConnection connection = this.connectionFactory.createTopicConnection()) { 
                try (TopicSession session = connection.createTopicSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)) {
                    try (MessageProducer messageProducer = session.createPublisher(this.topic)) { 
                        final ObjectMessage message = session.createObjectMessage(event);
                        messageProducer.send(message);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (final JMSException e) {
            log.error("Could not broadcast event to topic: " + event, e);
        }
    }

}
```

Snippet from standalone.xml:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:13.0">
    <server name="default">
        ...
        <jms-topic name="myTopic" entries="java:/jms/topic/myTopic"/>
        ...
    </server>
</subsystem>
```

*Outcome is that the messages are only consumed on the node that generated them. The other node does not receive any message.*

**Experiments**

I experimented by using `java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory` with durable subscripitions, unique `clientID` and `subscriptionName` for each node and a user "jmsuser",
and using a topic in java:jboss/exported (`java:jboss/exported/jms/topic/myTopic`), changing/extending the annotations on the MDB as follows:

```
...
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationLookup", propertyValue = "java:jboss/exported/jms/topic/myTopic"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "subscriptionDurability", propertyValue = "Durable"), 
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "subscriptionName", propertyValue = "subscription-${jboss.node.name}"), 
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "clientID", propertyValue = "node-${jboss.node.name}"), 
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "connectionFactoryLookup", propertyValue = "java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory"), 
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "user", propertyValue = "jmsuser"), 
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "password", propertyValue = "jmsuser")
...
```

Note: The "jmsuser" was added using the batch script add-user.bat in the wildfly/bin directory. It has been assigned the role "guest". The guest role has been extended regarding durable queues.
The property replacement in annotations (to make the `${jboss.node.name}` in `clientID` and `subscriptionName` work)
has been activated in standalone.xml:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:6.0">
    ...
    <annotation-property-replacement>true</annotation-property-replacement>
    ...
</subsystem>
...
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:13.0">
    <server name="default">
        ...
        <security-setting name="#">
            ...
            <role name="guest" delete-non-durable-queue="true"
               create-non-durable-queue="true"
               delete-durable-queue="true"
               create-durable-queue="true"
               consume="true"
               send="true" />
            ...
        </security-setting>
        ...
        <jms-topic name="myTopic" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/topic/myTopic"/>
        ...
    </server>
</subsystem>
...
```

The amended message publisher code:

```
public class ClusteredEventSender {

    @Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/exported/jms/topic/myTopic")
    private Topic topic;

    @Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory")
    private TopicConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    public void broadcast(final Serializable event) {
        try {
            try (TopicConnection connection = this.connectionFactory.createTopicConnection("jmsuser", "jmsuser")) {
                try (TopicSession session = connection.createTopicSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)) {
                    try (MessageProducer messageProducer = session.createPublisher(this.topic)) { 
                        final ObjectMessage message = session.createObjectMessage(event);
                        messageProducer.send(message);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (final JMSException e) {
            log.error("Could not broadcast event to topic: " + event, e);
        }
    }

}
```

*Experiments outcome: The connection to the RemoteConnectionFactory works, but nevertheless the behaviour remains the same as before.*

**My questions are:**
How can a publish / subscribe using JMS / ActiveMQ be implemented in a Wildfly cluster? What does the message driven bean look like, and how are the messages to be sent? What configuration is needed?

Comment: It is not clear what kind of clustering you are talking about. Are the broker clustered too ? Also if you want to consume messages on the broker on node1 from a MDB on node2 the connection factory should have a different configuration from the one on node1. You are not showing the real configuration you are using to connect to node1 broker nor node2 broker.

Comment: @ehsavoie Thank you for your feedback. As I am a novice, could you help me answering your questions: How do I tell whether my broker is clustered? In which aspects should the node1 and node2 connection factory configs differ? What is the "real" configuration, as I would be happy to share it here?

Comment: @ehsavoie I amended my question with the information that I am using the standalone full-ha profile, I hope this helps to shed additional light.

Comment: iirc the standalone full-ha doesn't create an artemis broker cluster. You need to create a connector towards the second node to be used by the resource adapter defined in your MDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @ehsavoie's hint we managed to solve the problem. Solution in short:

- Using `java:jboss/exported/jms/topic/myTopic` or `java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory` is not necessary. Neither are any `@ActivationConfigProperty`-Entries for `subscriptionName`, `clientId`, `user` or `password`. All experiments described in the question were a dead end.
- Creating a connector from node 1 to node 2 (as suggested in the comment) had some effect, since then node 1 was able to send events to node 2. Nevertheless, since we were using JGroups discovery (as in full-ha) this was merely a clue that the discovery was not working correctly.
- After changing the cluster password from the default "CHANGE ME!!" (duh!) and adding the attribute `jms-connection-factory="java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory"` to the `<default-bindings>` in our standalone.xml everything worked as expected. Those two little rascals slipped away during setup.

Thus, the relevant standalone.xml snippets are:

```
<cluster password="something else than CHANGE ME!!"/>
```

and

```
<default-bindings ... jms-connection-factory="java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" ... />
```

**Update**

For better orientation: The locations of the above mentioned snippets are:

```
<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:16.0">
    ...
    <profile>
        ...
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:13.0">
            <server name="default">
                <cluster .../>
                ...
            </server>
        </subsystem>
        ...
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:6.0">
            <default-bindings .../>
        </subsystem>
        ...
    </profile>
    ...
</server>
```

Comment: Where exactly did you add those snippets?

Comment: I figured out and add cluster tag inside server. Only adding cluster fixed my problem. Thanks!